# redux Action call other action fail

Tags: reactjs, redux

First, I want to call the action 'CLICK_SEARCH' to get the response from the server 
then pass the response to 'CLICK_SEARCH2' to update the store.

But its failure, the console result showing 'CLICK_SEARCH' instead of 'CLICK_SEARCH2' and action.payload is undefined. Anyone help? thx

```
 function reducreForSeach(state = initialState3, action) {
      if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return 0
      }

      switch(action.type) {
          case 'CLICK_SEARCH': {

            axios.post('abc/url', {
                responseType: 'document',
                headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},})
                .then(function(response) {

                 dispatch({
                 type:  'CLICK_SEARCH2',
                 payload: response.data});

          } 



          case 'CLICK_SEARCH2': {
           console.log(action.type);
           console.log(action.payload);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring constants for action types? Simple as this one:

```
const CLICK_SEARCH = 'CLICK_SEARCH';
const CLICK_SEARCH2 = 'CLICK_SEARCH2';

function reducreForSeach(state = initialState3, action) {
   //...other parts of the code
   switch(action.type) {
      case CLICK_SEARCH: {

         //...

         dispatch({ type: CLICK_SEARCH2,

      //...

      case CLICK_SEARCH2: {

      //...
```

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` is never defined or fed to the function `reducreForSeach`, so it will always fail to call CLICK_SEARCH2.

Chaining actions are not directly supported by Redux. You can implement by yourself, but I suggest you to look into popular libraries like [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) to learn how to call actions based on other action's result. They are all well-documented and recommended in [Redux's official website](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#what-async-middleware-should-i-use-how-do-you-decide-between-thunks-sagas-observables-or-something-else)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do such things in reducers as those are meant to be pure functions.

You can dispatch other actions from within action generators by using `redux-thunk` which enables you to return a function from your action generators.

The function you return will be called with `dispatch` as its props and allows you to further dispatch actions, from within the callback.

e.g.

```
export const mySearchActionGenerator = keyword => dispatch => {
    dispatch ({
       type: actionTypes.MY_SEARCH_ACTION
       keyword
    });
    dispatch ({
       type: actionTypes.MY_SEARCH_ACTION
       keyword
    });
}
```

Another option would be using `redux-saga` which allows far more complex setups.